# dispatch_after time triggers immediately

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

This is the first time I've used GCD, I'll admit, so sorry if I've been stupid. I have a dispatch_after command which acts as a handy delay for me.

My problem is that when I send

```
dispatch_after(500000000000, dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    println("triggered") //or any other code
}
```

the closure is triggered immediately (e.g. I have tested this and "triggered" prints immediately). It should take longer right? Like 500 seconds longer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first parameter of `dispatch_after(_:_:_:)` is not a delay, but a point in time. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after):

> *when*: The temporal milestone returned by `dispatch_time` or `dispatch_walltime`.
>
> **Discussion**
>   This function waits until the specified time and then asynchronously
>   adds block to the specified queue.

You need to construct a delay relative to the current time, using `dispatch_time(_:_:)`:

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(500 * NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }
```