# iOS dispatch_after is firing immediately

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, grand-central-dispatch, ios10, dispatch-async

I am trying to fire an event after 6 seconds using `dispatch_after`.

I'm firing a regular `dispatch_after` snippet (right built into Xcode itself).

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(duration + 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [do something];
});
```

`duration` is 6 seconds. However, `[do something]` executes instantly (I've got a breakpoint on it). I am on main thread/main queue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try change NSET_PER_SEC to NSEC_PER_MSEC and add your duration in MSEC or check this duplicate:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dispatch\_after time triggers immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949034/dispatch-after-time-triggers-immediately)

Comment: How exactly are you defining the value of `duration`¿

Comment: Oops, it was operand precedence. Back to simple math :) @l'L'l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple operator precedence error. My intention was to pass in a duration parameter but (in case `0` is passed) also add a small amount. `0.01` there.

I've mistakenly written `duration + 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC` trying to mean `(duration + 0.01) * NSEC_PER_SEC`, but because of operator precedence it was interpreted as `duration + (0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)`. I've added the parantheses and it started working correctly.